# How can I determine largest bit in a bitwise value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering if there is a short way (without programming the whole thing) of determining the largest number in a binary value in T-SQL.

In a column I store what days are selected (`1 = sunday, 2 = monday, .. 7 = saturday`) bitwise.

My translation table:

```
-- day of week
-- 1 == 1       -> POWER(2,0) -> sunday
-- 2 == 2       -> POWER(2,1) -> monday
-- 3 == 4       -> POWER(2,2)
-- 4 == 8       -> POWER(2,3)
-- 5 == 16      -> POWER(2,4)
-- 6 == 32      -> POWER(2,5)
-- 7 == 64      -> POWER(2,6) -> saturday
```

So if I select **FOR EXAMPLE** sunday and saturday my binary value is 65.

How can I select with `T-SQL` that `65` will be `7`??

---

**Edit**

Lets say I have two record with a two columns:

```
 ID   | SelectedDays 
------|--------------
 1    | 65
 2    | 3
```

So, `ID 1` will return 7, because that will be the saturday that is selected selected and `ID 2` will return monday.

Comment: Do you want some sort of set based solution or is a while / cursor okay?

Comment: split apart your combined column and make each day have its own single bit column

Comment: @JonH Well, ideally I want to write as little code as possible

Comment: can I suggest to edit your title to "How can I determine largest bit in a bitwise value". thanks

Comment: @LuisSiquot done. I was fighting myself to come up with a good title...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 SELECT FLOOR(LOG(bit_week)/LOG(2))+1
```

This returns 1 to 7 depending of the date.
`logaritm` is the inverse of `power` to obtanin logaritm in base 2, the trick is 'divide by the base'.  FLOOR, in its turn, provides the most significative bit.

Comment: This is very nice, but I think you want to add 1 to the result to get the day-of-week value (1-7), rather than the log2 value (0-6)

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use the second parameter to get the Log base 2 value, so I think your day of week would be:

```
FLOOR(LOG(binarycolumn,2)+1)
```

If not, you can do something kludgy like:

```
CASE WHEN BinaryColumn >=64 THEN 7
     WHEN BinaryColumn >=32 THEN 6
     WHEN BinaryColumn >=16 THEN 5
     WHEN BinaryColumn >=8  THEN 4
     WHEN BinaryColumn >=4  THEN 3
     WHEN BinaryColumn >=1  THEN 2
     ELSE                        1
     END
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but a `CASE WHEN` will cost more than some mathemetics operation I assume

Answer (score 1):

In C# you could do something like the following

```
        int i = 65;
        var b = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'); //pad to 8 bit binary
        var c = Math.Pow(2, 7 - b.IndexOf("1"));
```

-------- sorry missed the edit ------

```
var c = Enumerable.Range(0, b.Length).Where(x=>b[x] == '1').ToArray();
```

Comment: OK now c# answers aren't allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the C# input! Originally I was looking for just a T-SQL solution and then I changed my mind. After receiving a lot of SQL responses I changed my mind again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your enum as flags, then use can use it directly without any minupulation in SQL side as long as you store in INT column..

```
[Flags]
enum Day
{
  Sunday =1,
  Monday,
  Tuesday
  ....
  Saturday
}

var day = Day.Sunday | Day.Saturday //Internally enum will have bit flags set for 65.
```

You can insert this value in DB as integer.

To load it, just load the value of day and set the enum. Nothing needs to be done in SQL; just `SELECT Day FROM MyTable`

On your C#

```
//Sample query for retrieving 
Day day = (Day)db.ExecuteScalar("SELECT Day FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 'someid'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I never thought of using an enum in such a way

Answer (score 1):

The reverse of your POWER() calulation is to calculate by the inverse of the power (1/2). 
For example:
(for Mon, Wed, Fri = 2 + 8 + 32 = 42)
The inverse power would be POWER (42.0, (1.0/2.0)) = 6.5.  Truncate the decimal gives you 6. (Friday).

SELECT Convert(int, power(Convert(Decimal, SelectedDays), 0.5))

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for all the values with Saturday

```
select * from table where dayOfWeek >= 64
```